# Co-Administrator can't see subscription in new Azure portal

Tags: azure, portal

Simply, I have an Azure corporate subscription.  I have a co-administrator who has his own personal 90-day trial subscription.  When the co-administrator uses the new preview portal (manage.windowsazure.com) he can see their personal subscription (where he is admin) but cannot select or view the corporate subscription (where he is co-administrator).

Any ideas?  We want to have multiple people within our company assigned as co-administrators so they can play with the preview features (Virtual Machines, Azure Web Sites, Media Services).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main problem with Windows Azure preview portal is that if you are **account administrator** for any specific Windows Azure Subscription, it will only show configuration specific to that particular subscription when u used the live ID which is account administrator for other Windows Azure Accounts. If same live ID is **service administrator** of two different Subscriptions then in preview portal both subscription details will show up. This issue is related with Windows Azure Preview Portal and still in progress.

So if you want to solve this problem, you should use **OrgID/liveID** which is **service administrator** in multiple subscriptions (if applicable) this way that LiveID will shows details with both subscriptions.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand this answer. I'm a co-administrator, but I can't create websites for the subscription that I am a co-administrator of. Does that mean the service administrator needs to make me a service administrator as well? Can you have multiple service administrators on the same subscription? Or is it just not possible to do what I need to do?

Comment: Yes , I have the same question with Alex. Please help us.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem as well, in fact trying to see data via the resources.azure.com site was proving unfruitful.
As it turns out the new portal has its own user management features that are more granular than the admin/co-admin of the old portal.
Allow a subscription owner to make you a contributor or owner in the new portal and you should be able to see more data on the subscription via the new portal.
To do that:

1. As the service administrator, go to the new portal
2. Browse to Subscriptions
3. Locate & select the subscription you need to add users into
4. In the subscription details blade, select settings
5. Under resource management, select users
6. You'll notice that even though you are a co-admin, you're not listed among the users.
7. Add the user and make them a contributor/owner

There's more information on Azure's role-based access control here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/

Answer (score 5):

The Azure Admin has changed so the 2 current answers are outdated. Follow the following steps:

1. Open the subscription, click on 'my permissions' then 'click here to view complete access details for this subscription'
2. In Access Control (IAM), Click on Role assignments, then click Add
3. Choose 'Add role assignment' then choose the role to be 'Contributor' and choose which user you want to add from the right hand pane , then click Save.
4. Make sure the user is listed as a contributor under 'Role Assignments'